# invoke framework in termimal the window seems to be blocked

Tags: objective-c, macos, frameworks, dylib

now ,I have a framework named "MyFramework.framework" which include a window.nib, and I write a example to invoke it in terminal.
code:

```
//<MyFramework/myUI.h>

#ifndef Frmwork_myUI_h
#define Frmwork_myUI_h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{

#endif

void ShowDialog();

#ifdef __cplusplus

}
#endif

#endif

//test.mm

#include <MyFramework/myUI.h>

#include <Foundation/NSRunLoop.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    ShowDialog() ;
    while (!isTransmitCompleted)
    {
       [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
    return 0;

}
//build test.mm

g++ -c test.mm -o test.o

g++ test.o -o test -lpthread -framework Cocoa -framework AppKit -framework CoreData -framework Foundation -framework MyFramework

//run

$./test
```

the Dialog can appear, but it seems be blocked ,it has no focus , I can not input anything,  I can do nothing ,what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

now , I got the solution.

In OS X 10.6 ,I write a npapi plugin for Safari, In this plugin I invoke an framework which shows a Modal Window to get password. after close this modal window ,the Safari seems to block.

In my framework , I show this modal window by runModalForWindow function ,when I change to runModalSession , everything works perfectly. I don`t know why but it really works for me .